# JDBI - Bind Bean with List properties

Tags: java, jdbc, jdbi, jdbi3-core

I have a program using JDBI to query a Redshift cluster, and I'm struggling to generate the appropriate SQL statement using the `bindBean` functionality.

```java
@Data @Builder
public static class User {
    private String id;
    private List<String> emailAddresses;
}

private Jdbi createJdbi(
        @NonNull String jdbcUri,
        @NonNull String username,
        @NonNull String password) {
    RedshiftSimpleDataSource redshiftDataSource = new RedshiftSimpleDataSource();
    redshiftDataSource.setUrl(jdbcUri);
    redshiftDataSource.setUser(username);
    redshiftDataSource.setPassword(password);
    return Jdbi.create(redshiftDataSource);
}

public void jdbiQuery() {
    User user = User.builder()
            .id("1234")
            .emailAddresses(List.of("user@email.com", "email@user.com"))
            .build();
    String sqlTemplate =
            "SELECT id FROM Users WHERE id = :id AND email_address IN (:emailAddresses)";

    Jdbi jdbi = createJdbi(JDBC_URI, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

    List<String> userIds = jdbi.withHandle(
            handle -> handle.createQuery(sqlTemplate)
                            .bindBean(user)
                            .mapTo(String.class)
                            .list()
    );
}
```

The code above threw the exception: `org.jdbi.v3.core.statement.UnableToCreateStatementException: No argument factory registered for type [java.util.List<java.lang.String>]`.

I read that this could be fixed by registering the array type as follows:

```java
public void jdbiQuery() {
    .
    .
    Jdbi jdbi = createJdbi(JDBC_URI, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
    jdbi.registerArrayType(String.class, "varchar");
    .
    .
}
```

Indeed, that removed the exception, but then the final SQL statement generated was incorrect (notice how the IN clause is not correctly formatted).

```sql
SELECT id FROM Users WHERE id = '1234' AND email_address IN ('{"user@email.com","email@user.com"}')
```

Since the list identifiers to use the `bindList` functionality are enclosed in `<>`, I tried changing the SQL template to:

```java
   .
   .
    String sqlTemplate =
            "SELECT id FROM Users WHERE id = :id AND email_address IN (<emailAddresses>)";
   .
```

which resulted in the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.jdbi.v3.core.statement.UnableToCreateStatementException: Undefined attribute for token '<emailAddresses>'
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue? Any suggestion is welcome :)

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure that Redshift supports array type for column, are you sure that your desired query should use `IN` clause?

Comment: From the point of view array value binding everything looks good. For example, in PostgreSQL you could rewrite you query as `SELECT * FROM users WHERE email_address && :emailAddresses` and it would work fine with returning records with intersection of both arrays.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, the desired query should look like ```SELECT id FROM Users WHERE id = '1234' AND email_address IN ('user@email.com' ,'email@user.com')```, the ```IN``` clause is indeed supported by Redshift.

Comment: In the end, I got it to work by binding the lists and bean separately: ```handle -> handle.createQuery(sqlTemplate).bindBean(user).bindList("emailAddresses",user.getEmailAddresses()).mapTo(String.class).list()```

Comment: OK, just curious, what type is `email_adrdress`  column?